# Can't install expo-cli to use react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react-native and tried to install expo-cli in windows 10 following the page of react-native, id used the command npm init expo-cli and I have that error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'create-expo-cli@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Miguelangel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-24T11_01_08_933Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-expo-cli@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `create-expo-cli` package. It's just `expo-cli`.

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```